# Why does Huffman encoding have entropy?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Possible duplicate: [How are Huffman encoding and entropy related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181443/how-are-huffman-encoding-and-entropy-related)

I am confused on *why* you would calculate entropy, H, of some Huffman encoding implementation. I *understand the calculation* but it seems to me that calculating entropy is inappropriate because there are no error correcting properties of a Huffman code.

According to Dr. David MacKay's *Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms*, stream codes "will fail to decode correctly if any of the bits of the compressed files are altered."

That is the entire point of error correcting codes. Furthermore, to calculate the Shannon Limit, you must be able to model the communication channel in terms of its error distributions.

Unless I'm mistaken, there is no assumption of a *noisy channel* with canonical Huffman codes. Even so, I am seeing published papers that calculate the Shannon Entropy of a Huffman code.

Conceptually, why would you do this?

Edit: **Some additional information:**

I am seeing estimates for stream codes (variations on Lempel-Ziv) being referred to as the *Shannon Limit* for a channel. [According to Wikipedia's Noisy Channel page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem), `The Shannon limit or Shannon capacity of a communications channel is the theoretical maximum information transfer rate of the channel, for a particular noise level.`

What is bothering me is I'm seeing some entropy calculation for *Huffman codes* being presented as the *Shannon Limit* and I think that is incorrect.

I'm trying to figure out what I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: The connection that I'm aware of between Huffman coding and Shannon entropy is that the entropy (per symbol) of a source is an approximation to the average length of the words used in the Huffman code to represent the source symbols. (And the approximation tends to get better if you treat blocks of symbols as single symbols for coding purposes.) If you're asking about some other connection between Huffman codes and Shannon entropy, then it would be useful to specify what that connection is or at least where you've encountered it.

Comment: Hi @AndreasBlass thank you for the comment. That is exactly what I am asking. It makes sense to me to think of entropy in the context where you've constructed one Hamming code for lots of files, but conceptually I don't really see "the point" if you have a small amount of data. But even if it is the case where you have lots of files and a single Hamming code, and it's not a corner case, then the coding should be optimal anyway. Wouldn't that mean there's no redundancy? In which case, why bother with a Shannon information analysis? Edit: thinking on this; I believe you have a good answer for me